# Build MySQL 5.6.34 with openSSL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, openssl

I am trying to build MySQL 5.6.34 with openSSL support on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed openssl library by downloading and building the source [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz) 
The cmake command I used was the following:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/mysql/data -DSYSCONFDIR=/etc -DWITH_MYISAM_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 -DWITH_MEMORY_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/tmp/mysqld.sock -DMYSQL_TCP_PORT=3306 -DENABLED_LOCAL_INFILE=1 -DWITH_READLINE=1 -DWITH_PARTITION_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 -DEXTRA_CHARSETS=all -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DWITH_SSL=/usr/local/openssl
```

But I got the following message:

```
-- Running cmake version 3.4.3
-- MySQL 5.6.34
-- Packaging as: mysql-5.6.34-Linux-x86_64
-- HAVE_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- suffixes <.a;.so>
-- OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/local/openssl/include
-- OPENSSL_LIBRARY = /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a
-- CRYPTO_LIBRARY = /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a
-- OPENSSL_MAJOR_VERSION = 1
-- SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH - NOT FOUND
CMake Error at cmake/ssl.cmake:253 (MESSAGE):
  Cannot find appropriate system libraries for SSL.  Make sure you've
  specified a supported SSL version.  Consult the documentation for WITH_SSL
  alternatives
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:419 (MYSQL_CHECK_SSL)
```

Can anybody please help? I don't want to use `bundle` option. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but on macOS and adding the following flag (-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR) fixed it.

```
cmake .. -DWITH_JDBC=ON -DBUILD_STATIC=ON -DWITH_BOOST=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.72.0 -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/ -WITH_JDBC_TESTS=ON
```